# Getting "Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!" error while calling Gate

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug, laravel-8

I have defined a Policy named `UserPolicy` which goes like this:

```
class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        if(Gate::allows('edit', $user)){
            return view('admin.users.edit' , compact('user'));
        }
        abort(403);
    }
}
```

And at `AuthServiceProvider.php`, I have called it like this:

```
protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        User::class => UserPolicy::class
    ];
```

Then at the Blade, I added this:

```
@can('edit', $user)
   <a href="{{ route('users.edit' , ['user' => $user->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</a>
@endcan
```

But now, I get this error:

> Class 'App\Policies\Gate' not found

And when I call Gate like this at the Policy: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;`

This error occurs:

> Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!

So I tried adding `xdebug.max_nesting_level = -1` to `php.ini` but still the same error appears.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: have you restarted server after changing php.ini

Comment: @JohnLobo Yes, of course I have

Comment: check once commenting gate allow code if condtion.so you can verify the issue with that code or not .i am not sure about gates much since i havent used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not return anything except `boolean` in `Policy` class.You should return `false` or `true`.

Moreover when you use `Gate` inside the `policy` class you repeat the check `policy` class again and this causes an infinite loop.

So this is the right way:

```
public function edit(User $user)
{
    if($user_is_allowed_to_access){
        return true
    }
}
```